# implementing tf-idf in java with various applications

Tags: java, tf-idf, multifile-uploader

i have multiple tasks in mind regarding which i guess aim all at one thing i.e finding TF-IDF.

- I shall give N no. of documents and get all the words/names etc with highest relevance.(i know how to upload documents, i want to know how to give multiple documents as input to analyse them and not save them somewhere)
- I know how to analyse one document with stanford NLP and i get all the names,dates, locations etc. i want to compare the results with other documents to see if those strings of locations,dates,names etc repeat in other documents as well. if they do, then what is the frequency.
- I can make a search box and search for strings. what i want to make is  search for words from the files' data and get the documents that contain those words.(that's reading files from within)

All i need is a bit of guidance through the code. If only someone can solve any one of the given points.

Comment: Have you considered just using Elasticsearch or Solr? They both use Lucene, which supports TF-IDF.

Comment: Yes. I agree. These tools are probably what you want.

Comment: i have no idea about these. i'm only a beginner.  could you please guide me through these and how do they work? i'm searching about it on the internet too but it seems too vast

Comment: @gpeche  i did a little research about elasticsearch and turns out this is not what i need. it only deals with looking for files by name and description etc. i want to search through from the contents of the file. for eg i have a document which contains a name "xyz" in it....i should be able to find it. i could not find it anywhere that elasticsearch does that

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html